# youtube videos downloading using php to server

Tags: php, video, youtube, hosting, download

I am trying to download Youtube videos directly to hosting space. When i try the script on local server like xampp on my PC then it works well. but when i try the script on 000webhosting it do not works. It shows error like this

[See the problem i am having in this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyhkk.png)

the error is like below.

```
Uh oh, it looks like an error occurred: No MP4 video source was able to be located.
```

Below is PHP code for downloading Youtube video.

```
<?php

// What YouTube URL was provided to us?
$url = (string) @$_GET['url'];

/**
 * Define a function to extract a YouTube Video ID from a URL.
 *
 * @param    string    $url    A YouTube Video URL
 * @return    mixed            If successful, will return a string. If failed, will return NULL
 */

function getYouTubeVideoIdFromUrl( $url )
{
preg_match( "/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $url, $matches );

// If this match exists.
if ( sizeof( $matches ) >= 2 && strlen( $matches[1] ) )
{
    return $matches[1];
}

return NULL;
}

/**
* Define a function to extract a YouTube encoded stream URL.
*
* @param    array    $streams    An array of streams provided to us from YouTube's "get_video_info" page.
* @return    mixed                If successful, will return the MP4 stream URL. If failed, will return NULL
 */

function getMP4FromEncodedStream( $streams )
{
foreach( $streams as $stream )
{
    // Decode this stream's data.
    parse_str( $stream, $data );

    // If we found our MP4 stream source.
    if ( stripos( $data['type'], 'video/mp4' ) === 0 )
    {
        return $data['url'];
    }
}

// We didn't find any, whoops..
return NULL;
}

// Try to validate their request.
try
{
// If an invalid YouTube URL was provided.
if ( ( $videoId = getYouTubeVideoIdFromUrl( $url ) ) === NULL )
{
    throw new Exception( 'An invalid YouTube Video URL was provided.' );
}

// Retrieve all information pertaining to this Video; more specifically, we're looking for the encoded video streams.
parse_str( file_get_contents( 'http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' . $videoId ), $videoData );

// If there's a problem extracting information.
if ( @$videoData['status'] == 'fail' )
{
    throw new Exception( $videoData['reason'] );
}

// Were we able to locate an encoded stream in MP4 format?
if ( ( $streamUrl = getMP4FromEncodedStream( explode( ',', $videoData['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'] ) ) ) === NULL )
{
    throw new Exception( 'No MP4 video source was able to be located.' );
}

// Where will we be saving this Video?
$saveAs = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $videoId . '.mp4';

// Try to open the encoded video stream URL.
if ( $read = @fopen( $streamUrl, 'r' ) )
{
    // Open the file we want to save to.
    $write = @fopen( $saveAs, 'w' );

    // Write the stream to our file.
    $streamReturn = stream_copy_to_stream( $read, $write );

    // Close our files.
    @fclose( $read );
    @fclose( $write );

    // If we were unable to copy from stream.
    if ( $streamReturn === false )
    {
        throw new Exception( 'We were unable to copy this from the stream.' );
    }
}

// If our new file doesn't exist, we have a problem.
if ( !@file_exists( $saveAs ) )
{
    throw new Exception( 'We encountered an issue saving this Video.' );
}

// Everything saved properly, let them know there they can see their file.
print 'Your Video <strong>' . $videoId . '</strong> has been saved to <strong>' . $saveAs . '</strong>';
}
// If something went wrong.
catch( Exception $e )
{
print '<strong>Uh oh, it looks like an error occurred:</strong> ' . $e->getMessage( );
}

?>
```

All you need to do is copy this script to your webserver, and run the file with a URL like one of the following:

```
http://www.mywebserver.com/youtube-downloader.php?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
http://www.mywebserver.com/youtube-downloader.php?url=https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

All is working well but the videos are not downloading to online server, hosting space..

help ..
thanks in advance..

Comment: Remove all `@` and check if there's any error.

Comment: You should read [Youtube terms of use](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) at first.

Comment: okk.. i will try

Comment: removing @ also not worked

Comment: does the code work at localhost?  If yes, the youtube maybe blocking your host

Comment: yes the scripts works at local host and i other webhosting

Comment: but not working at 000webhost

Answer (score 4):

YouTube Video Downloader Library:

URL will look like this: http://localhost/index.php?vid=VIDEOID

```
$_GET['vid'] = 'VIDEOID';        
$vid = $_GET['vid']; //the youtube video ID

parse_str(file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $vid), $info); //decode the data

$videoData = json_decode($info['player_response'], true);
$videoDetails = $videoData['videoDetails'];
$streamingData = $videoData['streamingData'];
$streamingDataFormats = $streamingData['formats'];
//set video title 
$video_title = $videoDetails["title"];

print_r($streamingDataFormats[1]['url']);

$video = $streamingDataFormats[1]['url'];

file_put_contents("video-title-name.mp4", fopen($video, 'r'));

echo 'Youtube Video Download finished! Now check the file.';
```

Answer (score 1):

Install this package
https://github.com/socialAPIS/YoutubeDownloader

See this example
https://github.com/socialAPIS/YoutubeDownloader/blob/master/Examples/FetchPlayer.php

```
$video = file_get_contents($video_url);
file_put_contents($somedir . './videoplayback.mp4', $video);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `urlencode()` for your youtube url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://packagist.org/packages/athlon1600/youtube-downloader .This only depends on cURL and also gets updated regularly as of May 2020.You can install it via `composer require athlon1600/youtube-downloader`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

**Install**

`composer require vqhteam/ytdownload`

**Use**

```
<?php
use Vqhteam\Ytdownload\YTDownload;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
$get = YTDownload::getLink("Youtube Video Id");
var_dump($get);
?>
```

https://packagist.org/packages/vqhteam/ytdownload